# same image MP4 and png color differences

Tags: mp4, color

I'm making a 3D animation but, parts of it need to be static. I can use png renders for that, but pang format have slightly another color than mp4's. Because of this, ther's a visible difference when I put an mp4 and a static image after it, thought videp's frame is the same image as the static png.

How do I solve this problem?